# Creating New Model In workbench Error 998 Invalid access memory location windows 8

Tags: mysql, windows-8, mysql-workbench, workbench, memory-access

When I tried to Make a New DB Model Workbench

[image]

Then It Oppened the window of making New Diagrams

[image]

Then It Oppened these Error

[image]

Please Give Me Your Adivises

Comment: That sounds very much like a broken installation of MySQL Workbench or a general problem in the OS. Try reinstalling the app in its default location (e.g. via the MySQL Installer for Windows).

Comment: I've done that before but nothing happened